# Select value id in multi-select drop-down Laravel and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, laravel-5

I am working my way through a laravel form and did not realize until after the fact that my form needs a multiple select drop down. I have limited my code to what appears in the image. In my DB, the "tiers" populate as the id of 1, while the "specialties" populate as the name. I would like the specialty to populate as the id.

My view:

```
    <div class="container">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <strong>Select Country:</strong>

        <select id="multiple-checkboxes2" multiple="multiple" name="specialties" value="specialties_id">
         @if($specialties)
             @foreach($specialties as $specialty)
                <option>{{$specialty}}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        </div>

    </select>
        {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('tiers', 'Tiers:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('tiers',  $tiers, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
        {{ csrf_field() }}

  {!! Form::close() !!}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiple-checkboxes2').multiselect();
});
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    Client::create([

        'specialties' => $request->specialties,
        'tiers'=>$request->tiers,



     ] );


         return redirect('/accounts');
}
```

The pic below demos how the tiers portion of the form is bringing back a one, while the specialties is bringing back a name.

Comment: Not exactly related, but why do you have 3 `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form?

Comment: copying and pasting error on one of them, I watched a laravel demo where the instructor placed the {{ csrf_field() }} after each "form-group". If that is not necessary, I will only include one. Thanks. And in an attempt to shorten the question I left off some of my form

Comment: You need one `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside each `<form>...</form>`, but generally only for `POST` method forms (`method="POST"`). I don't think multiple will break anything, but it just looks... wrong. Anyway, to address the question, are you looking for `<option value="{{ $speciality->id }}">{{ $speciality->name }}</option>`? (`->name` can be substituted with a different attribute; not sure what `$speciality` is)

Comment: Here are the variables for my specialties/tiers in my display controller: $specialties=Specialty::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
      $tiers=Tiers::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

Comment: Then yeah, what I posted in the comments will translate to `<option value="1">Example</option>`, where `1` is the `$speciality->id`, and `Example` is `$speciality->name`. But, I don't really understand what you're asking in your question.

Comment: Yes, I think I need to revamp my eloquent so that I can use that attribute, because right now it isn't being regcognized

Comment: Ah maybe since you're using `->pluck()`? Do a `{{ dd($specialties) }}` and see what it is (in your Controller before returning it to the view)

Comment: I included a pic, but I don't think it worked... In my database I want my specialties to return as an id as the tiers do. But since I changed the format of the form, I need to change the eloquent call for the variables

Comment: array:2 [▼
  1 => "dsafsaf"
  2 => "dentist"
]